# Mat Datepicker not picking up primary color in dark mode

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I have been new to the angular theming and am trying to learn the concepts. I am working on switching between the dark mode and light mode. I have defined the scss file as below

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$my-primary: mat-palette($mat-gray, 900, 900, 900);
$my-accent:  mat-palette($mat-blue-grey, A200, A100, A400);
$my-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$my-theme: mat-light-theme($my-primary, $my-accent, $my-warn);

$primary: mat-color($my-primary);
$accent: mat-color($my-accent);
$warn: mat-color($my-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($my-theme);

.dark-theme {
  $dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-yellow);
  $dark-accent: mat-palette($mat-amber, A400, A100, A700);
  $dark-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
  $dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);

  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```

Whenever I am changing the primary color in light theme, the mat date picker is able to show me the correct color. However, when I am switching to dark mode, the color of date picker is still remaining as that of the light theme primary.

Here is the screenshot in light theme

[image]

However, it's not changing to the primary color of the dark theme, when switching to the dark theme.

[image]

Here, I was expecting the numbers to be highlighted in Yellow color.

Happy to share any details missing in my question.

Comment: `color: $light-primary-text;` got my attention

Comment: @canbax, thanks for pointing out. I tried removing that line, but still no change. I have edited the question as well